# Multiple buscador en modelos laravel

Tags: laravel, sql, select, buscador

Estimados estoy trabado en la realización de un buscador por favor agradecería toda clase de orientación.

En la vista tengo dos inputs.
Uno es un select que el usuario debe elegir el tipo de propiedad:
Alquiler - Venta - Temporal - Comercial

En el otro input debe escribir la ubicación.

VISTA BUSCADOR

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'busquedas', 'method' => 'get', 'class' => 'form-inline'])}}

                <select id="categoria" name="categoria" class="form-control">
                    {{-- <option value="" disabled>Seleccionar</option> --}}
                    @foreach($categorias as $index => $categoria)
                        <option value="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}">
                            {{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::text('ubicacion', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '¿Que ubicación está buscando? ']) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default question-btn">
                        <span class="fa fa-search">Buscar</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

En el controlador deseo filtrar en el modelo Category.php en base a la selección del usuario
Alquiler - Venta - Temporal - Comercial y además debo buscar en dos tablas la ubicación escrita.

En dos tablas por que por un lados está ubicación y por otra localidad que a su vez las mismas están relacionadas.

Modelo Propiedad:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function ubicacion(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Ubicacion::class);
}
```

Modelo Category:

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}
```

Modelo Ubicación:

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}

public function area(){
    //hasOne: una ubicacion tiene un area
    return $this->hasOne(Area::class);
}


public function scopeUbicacion($query, $ubicacion){
    if($ubicacion)
        return $query->where('ubicacion', 'LIKE', "%$ubicacion%");
}
```

Modelo Área:

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}

public function scopeArea($query, $area){
    if($area)
        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$area%");
}
```

En el controlador tengo hasta el momento lo siguiente:

```
$categoria = $request->get('categoria');
    $ubicacion = $request->get('ubicacion');

    $categoria_id = Category::where('nombre_categoria', $categoria)->pluck('id');


    $propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion'])

        ->when($categoria_id, function ($query) use ($categoria_id) {
            $query->where('category_id', $categoria_id);
        })
        ->when($ubicacion, function ($query) use ($ubicacion) {
            $query->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
        });
    })
    ->get();



    dd($propiedadesObtenidas);
```

No termino de encontrar una solución para unir las busquedas.

Por favor cualquier sugerencia será bienvenida. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que todo lo demás está funcionando como quieres, respondo a

> "¿Cómo unir las busquedas?"

Para el caso usaría la cláusula `when()` de Query Builder:

#### [Clausulas condicionales](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

En ocasiones, es posible que desees que las cláusulas se apliquen a una consulta solo cuando algo más sea verdadero. Por ejemplo, es posible que solo desees aplicar una instrucción `where` si un valor de entrada dado está presente en la solicitud entrante. Puedes lograr esto utilizando el método `when`:

```
Property::when($categoria_id, function ($query) use ($categoria_id) {
    $query->where('category_id', $categoria_id);
})->get();
```

El método `when` solo ejecuta la función de cierre dada cuando el primer parámetro (`$categoria_id`) es verdadero (funciona como un if`).` Si el primer parámetro es falso, el cierre no se ejecutará.

Entonces, en tu consulta sobre el modelo `Property`, puedes poner un `when` para cada filtro, que se ejecutará condicionalmente si el valor del filtro resulta en true (ten en cuenta que `null` resultará en false, por lo tanto si el usuario no rellenó el `input` de ese filtro, no buscas por ese valor).

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion'])
    ->when($categoria_id, function ($query) use ($categoria_id) {
        // cuando $categoria_id tenga algún valor que resuente en true, hacer este where
        $query->where('category_id', $categoria_id);
    })
    ->when($ubicacion, function ($query) use ($ubicacion) {
        // cuando $ubicacion tenga algún valor que resuente en true, hacer este where
        $query->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
            $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

Para la ubicación verás que usé whereHas, aquí la explicación:

#### [Consultar existencia de relación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Al acceder a los registros de un modelo, es posible que desees limitar sus resultados en función de la existencia de una relación, para el caso, puedes pasar el nombre de la relación al método `has`, o puedes usar el método `whereHas` para poner condiciones `"where"` en tus consultas de `has`. Este método te permite agregar restricciones personalizadas a una restricción de relación.

---

**EDIT:**
Si la categoría va a estar siempre presente, no hace falta el condicional, puedes poner directamente el `where`. Para las otras dos tendrías que dejar el condicional y [agrupar los parámetros](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping) (como ponerle paréntesis) y un OR para que devuelva datos si coincide una o la otra. Algo así:

```
    $propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion', 'area'])
        ->where('category_id', $categoria_id)
        ->when($ubicacion || $area, function ($query) use ($ubicacion, $area) {
            $query->where(function ($que) use ($ubicacion, $area) {
                $que->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                    $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
                })->orWhereHas('area', function ($q) use ($area) {
                    $q->area($area);
                });
            });
        })
        ->get();
```

---

**EDIT2**

O esta otra, que si el filtro tiene `$ubicacion` y `$area`, que busque una Property que cunpla las dos condiciones. Si el filtro no tiene las dos (`$ubicacion` y `$area`), que busque por la que tenga (`$ubicacion` o `$area`), y si no tiene ninguna, que devuelva todas las de la `$categoria`.

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::with(['category', 'ubicacion', 'area'])
            ->where('category_id', $categoria_id)
            ->when($ubicacion && $area, function ($query) use ($ubicacion, $area) {
                
                return $query->where(function ($que) use ($ubicacion, $area) {
                    
                    $que->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                        $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
                    })->whereHas('area', function ($q) use ($area) {
                        $q->area($area);
                    });
                    
                });
                
            }, function ($query) use ($ubicacion, $area) {

                return $query
                    ->when($ubicacion, function ($que) use ($ubicacion) {

                        $que->whereHas('ubicacion', function ($q) use ($ubicacion) {
                            $q->ubicacion($ubicacion);
                        });

                    })
                    ->when($area, function ($que) use ($area) {

                        $que->whereHas('area', function ($q) use ($area) {
                            $q->area($area);
                        });

                    });
            })
            ->get();
```

---

**EDIT3**

Algunas observaciones sobre los Modelos, las relaciones y la base de datos:

**Modelo Propiedad**:

```
public function category(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'category_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Propiedad
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function ubicacion(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'ubicacion_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Propiedad
    return $this->belongsTo(Ubicacion::class);
}

// esta es la relación que te falta declarar para hacer la consulta,
// pero necesitas esa columna 'area_id', 
// si no está en esta tabla, hay que hacer otra cosa, 
// como buscarla a través del modelo Ubicación
public function area(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'area_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Propiedad
    return $this->belongsTo(Ubicacion::class);
}
```

**Modelo Category**:

```
public function properties(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'category_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Propiedad
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}
```

**Modelo Ubicacion**:

```
public function properties(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'ubicacion_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Propiedad
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}

// esta está rara, ¿no será al revés? 
// "Una Ubicacion pertenece a un Area" 
// en vez de "Una Ubicacion tiene a un Area"
public function area(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'ubicacion_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Area
    return $this->hasOne(Area::class);
}

// este es un scope, generalmente se usa para segmentos de consultas
// que se repiten, y para que consultas complejas sean más fácil de leer
public function scopeUbicacion($query, $ubicacion){
    // para esta consulta necesitas tener un columna 'ubicacion'
    // en la tabla del modelo Ubicacion
    if($ubicacion)
        return $query->where('ubicacion', 'LIKE', "%$ubicacion%");
}
```

**Modelo Area**:

```
public function properties(){
    // para esta relación necesitas tener un columna 'area_id'
    // en la tabla del modelo Propiedad
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}

public function scopeArea($query, $area){
    // para esta consulta necesitas tener un columna 'name'
    // en la tabla del modelo Area
    if($area)
        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$area%");
}
```

Comment: Hola @porloscerros agradezco infinitamente tremenda explicación, estoy desde el viernes procesando tu respuesta. Sería formidable que pueda hacer funcionar esto pero lamentablemente no estoy encontrando el error. Me indica que tengo un error de syntax error, unexpected '}' por favor me puedes brindar un poco más de ayuda. Graciasss

Comment: Disculpa, me faltó un `;` antes del `->get(), es que lo escribí en el navegador y no me dí cuenta. Si necesitas alguna aclaración puedes preguntar. Ahí edité el código.

Comment: Hola @porloscerros gracias por tu pronta respuesta, ahora funciona pero me está trayendo un array vacío. Edite la pregunta para que veas como lo estoy haciendo. Entiendo que me faltaría que busque por el LIKE la palabra que escriba el usuario en ubicación no? en ubicación  tengo una relación a la tabla ubicación o el wereHas debería realizar la unión? gracias nuevamente y disculpa amigo que estoy tratando de hacer andar esto y vengo como bloqueado.

Comment: Hola, estimado @porloscerros anda perfecto!! encontre que no traía datos debido a que buscaba mal en la base, muchas gracias!! ahora necesito agregar que busque además en la tabla áreas pero creo saber como hacerlo. Gracias por tu explicación!!

Comment: Hola @porloscerros disculpa que te moleste de nuevo, es posible agregar una condición más? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376766/agregar-m%c3%baltiple-condici%c3%b3n-a-when-en-laravel

Comment: Hola. Entonces ¿la Categoría está siempre presente en el request, pero Ubicación y Area pueden estar los dos,, sólo uno de los dos, o ninguno? ¿Eso sería?

Comment: Hola @porloscerros si exacto, aunque el resultado de la búsqueda depende de lo que haya seleccionado en categoría. Categoría tiene un select con varias opciones. Es posible con el método que usted me enseño agregar esa condicional?

Comment: Edité la respuesta con una posibilidad. Decime si te sirve.

Comment: Hola @porloscerros estoy viendo que no funciona la búsqueda en área, al buscar una semejanza (LIKE) en área. Igualmente la verdad no tengo palabras para agradecerte, decime cuanto te debo  o como puedo retribuir tu gran ayuda!

Comment: Estoy viendo que Area está relacionado con Property, pero no a la inversa, o sea en el modelo Area dice que tiene muchas Property, pero en el model Property no dice nada de Area. ¿Hay una columna `area_id` en la tabla de Property? Si es así, tendrías que declarar la relación con Area, si no tendrías que consultar el Area a través de la Ubicacion. ¿se entiende?

Comment: Hola @porloscerros sumamente agradecido, que Dios te bendiga!! gracias por tanta generosidad!!